# expected '}' at end of input in my program main function

Tags: c++, compilation, syntax-error, curly-braces

This program is supposed to teach functions. I have separated the functions each into header files. I think there is a curly brace somewhere that is backwards or missing, but I have stared at this program for hours and tried re-arranging things and can't seem to get anything going.

This program is supposed to read a phone number and print it out. If it is provided letters then it will sort it to a number 0-9 like on a phone keypad, after making it an uppercase letter. It will also return error codes for invalid characters, etc., which is controlled by a switch statement.

#### Main function

One of the errors I am getting is on the closing brace on the last line:

> expected '}' at end of input

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include "Read_Dials.h"
#include "To_Digit.h"
#include "Acknowledge_Call.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5, digit6, digit7, digit8;
    int return_value = 0;

    return_value = int Read_dials(digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5, digit6, digit7, digit8);

    if (return_value != -5)
        break;

        switch(return_value){

            case -1:
            cout << "ERROR - An invalid character was entered. Please try again, only numbers or letters this time." << endl;
                break;
        case -2:
            cout << "ERROR - Phone number cant start with 0." << endl;
                break;
        case -3:
            cout << "ERROR - This isn't the movies, Phone numbers dont start with \" 555 \" here buddy :/" << endl;
                break;
        case -4:
            cout << "ERROR - Please make sure the hyphen is in position 4." << endl;
                break;
            default:
                void Acknowledge_Call(digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5, digit6, digit7, digit8);
        }
return 0;
}
```

#### Read_Dials Function

No errors in this function

```
int Read_Dials(char &num1, char &num2, char &num3, char &num4, char &num5, char &num6, char &num7, char &num8)
{

#include "To_Digit.h"

int i = 0;

    do{
    i++;
    cout << "Please enter the character for position #" << i << " in the phone number\n";
    cout << "NOTE: Please put the hyphen \" - \" in the fourth position and use \"Q\"to quit." << endl;
    char temp;
    cin >>temp;

        if (i = 1 && temp == 0)
        {
            return_value = -2;
        }
        else if (i == 1 && (temp == 'q' || temp == 'Q'))
        {
            return_value -5;
        }

        else if (i == 1)
        {
            temp = &num1;
            &inputValue = &num1;
            int To_Digit(char &num1);       
        }
        else if (i == 2)
        {
            temp = &num2;
            &inputValue = &num2;
            int To_Digit(char &num2);
        }
        else if (i == 3)
        {
            temp = &num3;
            &inputValue = &num3;
            int To_Digit(char &num3);
        }
        else if (&num1 == '5' && &num2 == '5' && &num3 == '5')
        {
            return_value -3;
        }
        else if (i == 4 && temp != '-')
        {
            return_value -4;
        }
        else if (i == 5)
        {
            temp = &num5;
            &inputValue = &num5;
            int To_Digit(char &num5);
        }
        else if (i == 6)
        {
            temp = &num6;
            &inputValue = &num6;
            int To_Digit(char &num6);
        }
        else if (i == 7)
        {
            temp = &num7;
            &inputValue = &num7;
            int To_Digit(char &num7);
        }
        else if (i == 8)
        {
            temp = &num8;
            &inputValue = &num8;
            int To_Digit(char &num8);
        }
    }while (i < 8)
    return 0;
}
```

#### To_Digit Function

The second and final error I'm getting is here, on the second line (the opening brace):

> A function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

```
int To_Digit(char &inputValue)
{

char &inputValue;

    if (isdigit(&inputValue))
        break;

    &inputValue = toupper(&inputValue);

    switch(&inputValue){

        case 'A': case 'B': case 'C':
            &inputValue = '2'; 
                break;

        case 'D': case 'E': case 'F':
            &inputValue = '3'; 
                break;

        case 'G': case 'H': case 'I':
            &inputValue = '4'; 
                break;

        case 'J': case 'K': case 'L':
            &inputValue = '5'; 
                break;

        case 'M': case 'N': case 'O':
            &inputValue = '6'; 
                break;

        case 'P': case 'Q': case 'R': case 'S':
            &inputValue = '7'; 
                break;

        case 'T': case 'U': case 'V':
            &inputValue = '8'; 
                break;

        case 'W': case 'X': case 'Y': case 'Z':
            &inputValue = '9'; 
                break;
        default:
            return -1;

    }
}
```

#### Acknowledge_Call function

No errors with this function.

```
void Acknowledge_Call(digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5, digit6, digit7, digit8)
{
    cout << "Phone number entered is: " << digit1 << digit2 << digit3 << digit4 << digit5 << digit6 << digit7 << digit8 << endl;
}
```

What's wrong with this code? How can I fix it?

Comment: This is impossible to read. You should edit your post for readability.

Comment: please edit your question to be more clear and readable by using code blocks and also including the compiler error.

Comment: I'm going to guess the problem is in one of your header files, not in the cpp.

Comment: Locate and use the `{}` above the text box to format your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
 default:
     void Acknowledge_Call(digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4, digit5, digit6, digit7, digit8);
```

Return type is not used while calling a function. So, drop `void`. Also `default` case should  have a `break`, else it will *fall-through*.

---

```
int Read_Dials(char &num1, char &num2, char &num3, char &num4, char &num5, char &num6, char &num7, char &num8)
{

   #include "To_Digit.h"  // The header actually has a definition. Preprocessor 
                          // copies the content of To_Digit.h here. So, you have
                          // a function definition inside another function while 
                          // compilation phase which is not allowed. So remove
                          // it and place it at top of the file.
   // .....

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried to run the code myself just yet, but the only thing I can see that looks hokey to me is in the "Read_Dials" function... don't put a #INCLUDE statement within a function.  Always place those statements at the top of the file.

Move the #include and let us know what that does.
Good luck.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the #include thing was the cause behind the missing } error.

Answer (score 2):

Your #includes should be at the top of the file...

```
if (return_value != -5)
    break;
```

(in main) is not allowed as there is no loop for it to break out of

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues (besides the fact you didn't supply header files):

1. Function declaration after "default" in `main()`
   Remove the `void` in front of the function call.
2. Types for parameters not specified in declaration for `Acknowledge_Call`
   Change to:
   `void Acknowledge_Call(char digit1, char digit2, char digit3, char digit4, char digit5, char digit6, char digit7, char digit8)`
3. Remove the `int` in front of `Read_dials` in the `main` function.
4. In `main()`, change 'Read_dials`to`Read_Dials`:

   The C++ language is case-sensitive, thus 'dials` != `Dials` != `dIaLs`.
5. Remove `break` from after `if` in `main()` function:
   You want `return 1;` or `return EXIT_FAILURE;` or `exit(1);`
6. Remember to add these lines to `Acknowledge_Calls.cpp`:

   `#include "acknowledge_call.h"`
   `#include <iostream>`
   `using namespace std;`
7. Remember to add these lines to `Read_Dials.cpp`:

   `#include "read_dials.h"`
   `#include <iostream>`
   `using namespace std;`
8. In `Read_Dials.cpp`, move the `#include "To_Digit.h` to the top of the file.
9. When executing a function all, do not put the return type nor the parameter types in the call.
   For example, use:
   `num1 = To_Digit(digit1);`
   instead of
   `int To_Digit(char &num1);`

You need to have a long talk with your instructor about how to call functions and pass parameters (this time, listen carefully).  Also, read a **good** book on C++.